# How it is possible to call methods of Object class on a reference of Interface type?

Tags: java, interface

```
interface TestInterface{
   public void sayHello();
}

class A implements TestInterface{ 

   public void sayHello(){
       System.out.println("Hello");
   }

   public void sayBye(){
       System.out.println("Hello");
   }

   public String toString(){
       return "Hello";
   }

   public static void main(String args[]){
       TestInterface ti=new A();
       ti.sayHello();  
       ti.sayBye();//error
       ti.toString();//How toString method can be called as it is not the part of the interface contract.
   }
}
```

Comment: See the JLS: _"If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface implicitly declares a public abstract member method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t corresponding to each public instance method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t declared in Object, unless a method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by the interface."_ Assuming that you have `interface TestInterface {}`.

Comment: Thanks Alexis: That means interface TestInterface implicitly has declaration for all the object methods.

Comment: @Pankaj: Yup, that's what it means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this section in the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2):

> If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface implicitly declares a `public abstract` member method m with signature s, return type r, and `throws` clause t corresponding to each `public` instance method m with signature s, return type r, and `throws` clause t **declared in `Object`**, unless an `abstract` method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by the interface.

So `Object`'s public methods like `toString` are implicitly declared in all interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

`toString` can be called because any implementation of any interface must be a sub-class of Object, which contains the `toString` method.

In order to call any other method that doesn't appear in the interface or in any super-interface your interface extends (and is not defined in `Object` class), you must cast the interface to the type of the class that contains that method.

Answer (score 0):

Every *object* is an `Object` :) It would make sense to call `Object` methods on *objects*.

That's the heart of the matter - all reference types are [subtypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10) of `Object`. Reference types include

- class type
- interface type
- array type
- type variable (`T`)
- null type  (for `null`)
- intersection type ( `A&B` )

A subtype inherits methods from the supertype. Therefore all reference types inherit `Object` methods.

Answer (score -2):

This is the nature of OO Languages. Interfaces only define a set of method signatures that a concrete class needs to implements. They don't restrict the nature of the class (abstract v concrete).

So when you declare `TestInterface ti`, in your example `A` implements `TestInterface`, so it is an instance of `TestInterface`. Likewise `class B implements TestInterface {...}` is also valid.

```
TestInterface ti = new A(); // Valid
              ti = new B(); // Also valid (given the above definition)
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not answer the question.

Comment: Thanks, I have now re-reading the question a with a keener eye for detail.